# Acumatica unable to publish the Customization Package

Tags: acumatica, aspose.words

I am trying to publish the customization package on Acumatica Version 17.204.0019.

But I am getting the following error :

```
Validating Binary Files
Aspose.Words.dll Method signature was changed: System.Void   [0...,0...]::.ctor(System.Int32,System.Int32) declared in Aspose.Words.dll
Aspose.Words.dll Failed to resolve method reference: System.Void   [0...,0...]::Set(System.Int32,System.Int32,  ) declared in Aspose.Words.dll
Aspose.Words.dll Failed to resolve method reference:      [0...,0...]::Get(System.Int32,System.Int32) declared in Aspose.Words.dll
Aspose.Words.dll Failed to resolve method reference:    /&    /[0...,0...]::Address(System.Int32,System.Int32) declared in Aspose.Words.dll
Aspose.Words.dll Method signature was changed: System.Void    /[0...,0...]::.ctor(System.Int32,System.Int32) declared in Aspose.Words.dll
```

We  have installed Aspose.Words via Nuget Package Manager  and we want to include it in package. But as you see Acumatica is trying to validate Aspose.Words.dll bynary files.
How can we disable to validate binary files while publishing the customization package? Or how to solve problem? In package we have correctly included every dll(Copy Local property is set to true on aspose dll).

Comment: Please check [Install Customized Package on Acumatica](http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/05/install-customized-package-on-acumatica.html). We will check it with our product team if this issue is at Aspose.Words' end. A related issue was fixed in Acumatica. Please check [this](https://github.com/Acumatica/acumatica-boxstorageprovider/issues/1) link. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: We know how to publish package

Comment: Forgot to mention, we are using Apose.Words 15.12.0 version

Comment: Please try latest version of [Aspose.Words for .NET 18.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/). Hope this helps you.

Comment: Getting the same error. I think it relates to Acumatica not to Aspose.Words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, it's too soon to confidently say, whether this behavior is caused by a potential issue with Acumatica binary file validation or something else. All details had been forwarded to Acumatica Engeeniring Team for further investigation. Will post an update here as soon as I hear back from engineering.

---

**Based upon the response from engineering, to get over this issue you should proceed as follows**:

1. Create a **cstValidationIgnore.txt** text file in your local Acumatica ERP website's **App_Data** folder
2. Copy all 5 error messages generated for Aspose.Words.dll from the Compilation dialog and paste them into the **cstValidationIgnore.txt** text file created on step 1 (during the Binary Validation stage errors listed in the cstValidationIgnore.txt text file will be ignored)
3. Open the Customization Manager and include **cstValidationIgnore.txt** text file into the customization project, that already contains Aspose.Words.dll
4. Republish the customization