# Acumatica Publishing with DLL resulting in System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add some external DLLs  to the Acumatica Customisation project but upon publishing it results in "System.BadImageFormatException: Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid."

Error Image: 
[image]

I already have added multiple DLLs to the Customisation. And was using the method specified here: [Acumatica unable to publish the Customization Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48679096/acumatica-unable-to-publish-the-customization-package) to skip over the errors, but in this case it does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The first step should be identifying which DLL is the culprit. I suggest you create an empty project and put the files in there one by one with the ignore rules. Maybe you missed to add ignore rule for one of the files.

This error happens because Acumatica attempts to parse the DLL as a .Net framework assembly. If you add non .Net assembly such as native x86/x64 compiled libraries you need to add the ignore rule so Acumatica doesn't attempt to parse it.

If the error is coming from a DLL you compiled, make sure it was compiled in `Any CPU` platform. This prevents any incompatibility related to 32 bit/64 bit mismatch.

[image]

Comment: I know which DLLs are causing these issues, and they are not compiled by myself but are third party DLLs. Unfortunately they are compiled either x86 or x64 not under the Any CPU configuration plus they are unmanaged DLLs. How would I add an ignore rule to Acumatica please? Thanks

Comment: Ignore rules are added using the method you linked to in your question. Two things can be happening here. 1. The ignore rule isn't set up properly, that's why I suggested double check and working one file at a time. 2. Newer version of Acumatica don't use ignore rule the same way or contains a bug. I think this is less likely but should be testable. If same project works in old version then it points toward a bug in the product. Documentation on ignore rules: https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(2))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=282cc58a-4700-4e9d-8cf6-4641e625c0d6

Comment: Ahh ok..thought there is a way to ignore a whole DLL not just the error messages that it gives you. I tried adding the error message to the ignore rules but unfortunately it is still resulting in the same error message :/

Comment: I think the ignore rules are the only way to go so you need to double check if you properly put the error messages in there (as is, exact copy/paste). This is an example of what that file contains for an external DLL which needed an ignore rule: PdfPrintingNet.dll Failed to resolve method reference: PdfEdit.Drawing.BarCodes.CodeBase/c070bf7cf4300b5656d19c5f7e7750043& PdfEdit.Drawing.BarCodes.CodeBase/c070bf7cf4300b5656d19c5f7e7750043[0...,0...]::Address(System.Int32,System.Int32) declared in PdfPrintingNet.dll

Comment: In your case that would be copy paste of: System.BadImageFormatException… up to line 133

Comment: Or it could be from System.BadImageFormatException… up to is invalid.

Comment: Is there evidence that it ever worked before? At this point while it's the only option available I can't confirm that the parsing of assemblies can be circumvented by ignore rules.

Comment: The ignore rules do work because I have another 50 rules for other DLLs there that work as expected. Unfortunately for the BadImageFormatException it does not seem to work, for some reason. I tried all variations with and without the stack trace but it never manages to publish.

Comment: There's reason to believe loading of assemblies for parsing could occur before ignore rules are applied. A possible workaround would be to put the unmanaged library elsewhere (not in bin folder). You could use GAC util to put it in the GAC and Acumatica shouldn't parse files out of Bin directory. I don't think there's a way to directly avoid the issue in Bin folder without recompiling the product so you could consider opening a support ticket if you work with an Acumatica partner.

Comment: To be clear either C# wrapper calling the unmanaged DLL in GAC or another more simple trick that could work is dropping the unmanaged DLL in windows/system32 folder since it's part of the search path for libraries.